# How to play Metal Gear Solid V Ground Zeroes on Windows 10 x64

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

I can't run Metal Gear Solid V Ground Zeroes on Windows 10 x64.

Error,

[image]

Specs,

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support while not meeting the minimum requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the CPU itself (4C/4T *Sandy Bridge* @ 3.3-3.7 GHz) can run the game, you're on processor (integrated) graphics, and the Intel HD Graphics 2000 does not support DirectX 11.

You'll need to install a discrete graphics card to run the game. Most new graphics cards have DirectX 11 support. The system requirements are fairly low; they specify a GeForce GTX 650 as minimum and a GeForce GTX 760 as recommended. I would suggest the newer GTX 1050, though there are faster cards out there. Before you buy a graphics card, be sure to check if your system can accept the card, including power (and PCIe auxiliary power connector) requirements.